# Как выровнять съехавшие колонки по центру по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap 5. Пробовала выравнивать justify-content-center, align-self-center, margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Business Cards</title>
  <style>
    .col--hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      width: 60%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .card-group {
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    #img {
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 "></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
    async function getCards() {
      let response = await fetch(url);
      cards = await response.json();
      cardsData = cards.data;
      cardsList = document.querySelector('.row');

      for (key in cardsData) {
        cardsList.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="col col--hidden align-self-center" >
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="${cardsData[key].avatar}" class="card-img-top"  width="200" height="200" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${cardsData[key].first_name} ${cardsData[key].last_name}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">${cardsData[key].email}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    `
      }
      $(".col--hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('col--hidden');
    }

    getCards();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что значит "выровнять съехавшие колонки"? Весь контент Вам надо по центру поместить? По центру от чего, вертикали или горизонтали?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar выровнять по центру по горизонтали

Comment: На `row` добавьте `justify-content-center` [подробнее](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

Comment: @Simon не работает, все равно слева

Answer (score 1):

К `card-group` нужно добавить `justify-content-center`, так как `card-group` имеет свойство `display: flex`.

```js
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
async function getCards() {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  cards = await response.json();
  cardsData = cards.data;
  cardsList = document.querySelector('.row');

  for (key in cardsData) {
    cardsList.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="col col--hidden align-self-center" >
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="${cardsData[key].avatar}" class="card-img-top"  width="200" height="200" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${cardsData[key].first_name} ${cardsData[key].last_name}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">${cardsData[key].email}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    `
  }
  $(".col--hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('col--hidden');
}

getCards();
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card-group {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card-group justify-content-center">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4 "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: я писала, что justify-content-center у меня не работает

Comment: @name4less Пример Ваш в ответе? Получается, всё работает. Возможно, Вы пытаетесь выравнивать не тот блок (на `row`, может быть)

Answer (score 0):

Вот полный код html

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Business Cards</title>
  <style>
    html {
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .col--hidden {
      display: none;
      margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    
    .row {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      width: 250px;
      height: 300px;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .card-group {
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    .col {
      align-items: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    #img {
      border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
    
    .loadMore {
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      width: 500px;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Business Cards</span>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="card-group justify-content-center">
    <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="loadMore" class="loadMore"> Load More </a>

  <footer>
    <div class="text-center p-4" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);">
      © Nimchenko Anastasiya 2021
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script>
    const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';
    async function getCards() {
      let response = await fetch(url);
      cards = await response.json();
      cardsData = cards.data;
      cardsList = document.querySelector('.row');

      if (cardsData) {
        for (key in cardsData) {
          cardsList.innerHTML += `
                    <div class="col col--hidden" >
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="${cardsData[key].avatar}" class="card-img-top"  width="200" height="200" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${cardsData[key].first_name} ${cardsData[key].last_name}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">${cardsData[key].email}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                    `
        }
      } else {
        cardsList.innerHTML += `<p>Данные отсутствуют</p>`
      }
      $(".col--hidden").slice(0, 3).removeClass('col--hidden');
    }

    getCards();
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(".col--hidden").slice(0, 3).slideDown().removeClass('col--hidden');

          $(this).toggle();
        })
      })
    });
    //$(document).ready(JSONToCSVConvertor(cardsData));
  </script>
  <!-- <script>
            function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData) {    
            var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;   
            var CSV = '';     
        
            for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
                var row = "";
                for (var index in arrData[i]) {
                        var arrValue = arrData[i][index] == null ? "" : '="' + arrData[i][index] + '"';
                        row += arrValue + ',';
                }
                row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
                CSV += row + '\r\n';
            }
            if (CSV == '') {        
                growl.error("Invalid data");
                return;
            }   
            var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = uri;
            link.download = fileName + ".csv";
            document.body.append(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.remove(link);
        }
        </script> -->
</body>

</html>
```